# Azure Ultra Disks: How to Downgrade Ultra disk to Premium SSD?

Tags: azure, database-administration, disk

We have tempdb and log files on 2 separate Ultra disks on an Azure VM. Since usage is not that high we would like to downgrade them to Premium SSDs.
Is it possible to do it or we have to attach new SSDs, move files to them and then delete Ultra disks? I am looking around and can't find anything about that.

Thanks.

Nothing on the MSFT site about it that I could find.
Tried on a VM to downgrade it but couldn't find an option to do it.
Searched web, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-enable-ultra-ssd?tabs=azure-portal#ga-scope-and-limitations), changing the new disk type is not supported for ultra disk.

[image]

You need to create an empty disk and [attach both disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/faq-for-disks#ultra-disks) to same VM and copy the disk data from one disk to other or leverage a 3rd party solution for data migration.

Comment: Yes, I saw it and I was afraid of that.

Thanks.